# Linq DateTime Difference sum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a a group by and I'd like to find the difference between two dates and then add the result to the final sum. But I keep getting the Error that can't convert from timespan to Long.
This is the code that I used:

```
var summary = (
  from p in db.CP_SDV_Acc
  where p.Scandate >= start && p.EndDate <= end && p.Device==divice
  let k = new
  {
    //try this if you need a date field 
    //   p.SaleDate.Date.AddDays(-1 *p.SaleDate.Day - 1)
    Device = p.Device,
  }
  group p by k into t
  select new OeeRecovery
  {
    Device = t.Key.Device,

    GoodPcs = t.Sum(p => p.GoodPcs),
    BadPcs=t.Sum(p=>p.BadPcs),
    Oee =(decimal)(t.Sum(p => p.GoodPcs)- t.Sum(p => p.BadPcs)) / t.Sum(p => p.GoodPcs),
    WorkTime = t.Sum(x=>new TimeSpan(x.EndDate-x.Scandate).TotalMilliseconds??TimeSpan.Zero)

    //t.Sum(new TimeSpan( p =>  p.EndDate - p.Scandate))
    //t.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, it) =>total += (it.EndDate-it.Scandate)),
}).ToList();
```

`WorkTime` is a `TimeSpan` type and `Enddate` and `scandate` are `DateTime` type.
How could i get the sum of timespan?

Comment: does this expression with the null-coalesce operator (`??`) even compile? `new` will always return an instance, so what do you expect here? Note that `TotalMilliseconds` is a `double` and `TimeSpan.Zero` is a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I get the error in the (x.EndDate-x.Scandate)

Comment: Quickest fix for this (just to get it not to fail, would be to change TimeSpan.Zero to TimeSpan.Zero.TotalMilliseconds. Then both parts of the null coalese will be returning the same type, and then it will be boxed to Long automatically. In addition, you dont need to have the new TimeSpan, because subtracting two date values returns a TimeSpan. So you could just do: (x.EndDate-x.ScanDate).TotalMilliseconds??TimeSpan.Zero.Milliseconds, or even simpler (x.EndDate-x.ScanDate).TotalMilliseconds??0

Comment: What EF version are you on (EF6 or EF Core)?

Comment: its EF6  ,no more errors but crashed when i try to get data LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromMilliseconds(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging task mainly because LINQ to Entities does not support most of the CLR methods/properties/operators of `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`.

The only solution I see is to use [`DbFunctions.DiffSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffseconds(v=vs.113).aspx) canonical function to get the difference in seconds, sum them up and then convert to `TimeSpan` using another canonical function [`DbFunctions.CreateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createtime(v=vs.113).aspx), manually calculating hours, minutes and seconds from total seconds:

```
...
group p by k into t
let workSecs = t.Sum(x => DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(x.Scandate, x.EndDate)) ?? 0
select new OeeRecovery
{
    ...
    WorkTime = DbFunctions.CreateTime(workSecs / 3600, (workSecs / 60) % 60, workSecs % 60)
    ...
}
```

Comment: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  I do not see any string in there and it's only crashes at runtime

Comment: I don't see either. It's something you are the only one who can figure out, because I've tested the above construct on sample table with `DateTime` fields and it works. You could start by commenting out both `let workSecs = ...` and `WorkTime = ...` lines and see if you still get runtime exception.